# Adding vanilla flavor to non-fat plain greek yogurt

Tags: yogurt

Having read the question [How to get the flavors to meld when I add fruit and sugar to plain yogurt?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/22397/adding-flavor-sweetness-to-plain-greek-yogurt), I still have a question. I enjoy vanilla-flavored greek yogurt. I know pure vanilla extract is a very strong flavoring. How much vanilla should I add to a cup of plain greek yogurt? How much Splenda to the same amount of yogurt?

Answer (score 5):

This is a matter of taste.  You should experiment and see what you prefer.

Based on these blog entries chosen because they come early in search results for "homemade vanilla yogurt"

- [Blissfully Content Life](http://www.theblissfullycontentlife.org/2013/04/making-homemade-yogurt.html)
- [Vintage Mixer](http://www.thevintagemixer.com/2012/08/homemade-vanilla-bean-yogurt-recipe/)

you might want to start your experimentation with the following ratios:

- 3 tablespoons of vanilla per gallon of yogurt
- 3/4 cup sugar equivalent per gallon of yogurt

On a per cup basis, this works out to about 1/2 teaspoon of vanilla, and 2 1/4 teaspoons of sugar or equivalent.

Comment: Great! Now I have a place to start!

Answer (score 0):

Don't remember where I got it;
32 oz container, 
1 teaspoon vanilla
a little less than a 1/4 teaspoon cinnamon
3 tablespoons powdered sugar

Good luck,

Ron

Answer (score -1):

32 oz. of Greek yogurt,
2 tsp. vanilla extract,
a scant 1/2 cup of Splenda.

Mix well and enjoy.  I prefer my yogurt a little on the sweet side.  So experiment.